# How to reorganize a list in specific way in Python

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

So, what I am trying to do is if you have the following list:

```
example_list=['This', 'is', 'QQQQQ', 'an', 'QQQQQ', 'example', 'list', 'QQQQQ', '.']
```

I want it to be reorganised as this:

```
example_list=['This is', 'an', 'example list', '.']
```

Notice how QQQQQs are being used as placeholders. So, basically I want everything between the QQQQQs to be one list element. How do I do that?

I have seen other posts about the  join() function, but the problem I have is putting a space in between, if there is more than 1 word.

Comment: @dfundako that doesn't solve the space issue.

Answer (score 4):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
example_list=['This', 'is', 'QQQQQ', 'an', 'QQQQQ', 'example', 'list', 'QQQQQ', '.']

res = [[]]
for i in example_list:
    if i == "QQQQQ":
        res.append([])
    else:
        res[-1].append(i)
print([" ".join(i) for i in res])
```

**Output:**

```
['This is', 'an', 'example list', '.']
```

Comment: what is `res[-1]` for?

Comment: @Rakesh Really not a big deal, I'm just wondering why linking the dupe ?

Comment: Sorry, but I have problems understanding why `res[-1].append(i)` works the way it does.

Comment: Try:  `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `print(a[-1])` it should print `5`

Comment: @scharette..Sorry did not notice that it was a dupe

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> example_list=['This', 'is', 'QQQQQ', 'an', 'QQQQQ', 'example', 'list', 'QQQQQ', '.']
>>> [' '.join(g) for k, g in groupby(example_list, lambda x: x == 'QQQQQ') if not k]
['This is', 'an', 'example list', '.']
```

Or even with [`.__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) comparison, as suggested by [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634279/how-to-reorganize-a-list-in-specific-way-in-python?noredirect=1#comment90233044_51634393) in the comments:

```
>>> [' '.join(g) for k, g in groupby(example_list, key='QQQQQ'.__eq__) if not k]
['This is', 'an', 'example list', '.']
```

Comment: You could also use `key='QQQQQ'.__eq__` (not sure if that's better, though)

Comment: @tobias_k That's a cool way to use `key`. Updated answer to also include it :).

Answer (score 2):

Try `join` together with `strip()` to get rid of white spaces

```
answer = [s.strip() for s in ' '.join(map(str, example_list)).split('QQQQQ')]
print (answer)
```

**Output**

```
['This is', 'an', 'example list', '.']
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: Do a join with space and then just add the spaces to placeholder in a split function.

**Example:**

```
example_list = ['This', 'is', 'QQQQQ', 'an', 'QQQQQ', 'example', 'list', 'QQQQQ', '.']

print(' '.join(example_list).split(' QQQQQ '))
```

**Result:**

```
['This is', 'an', 'example list', '.']
```

or more generalized:

```
split_arg = ' {} '.format(place_holder)
example_list = ' '.join(example_list).split(split_arg)
```

**edit after comment by tobias_k**

comment was: "Of course, this only works if the placeholder actually is a string, and if that stirng does not appear in any of the other words. I.e. it would not work if the placeholder was, e.g., None, 'Q', or '' – tobias_k"

Which is true, so I made an even more generalised solution so it should work for each placeholder.

```
import random
import string

example_list = ['This', 'is', None, 'an', None, 'example', 'list', None, '.']
place_holder = None
# create a random string of length 10
random_place_holder = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=10))  
# Replace all old place holders with our new random string placeholder
example_list = [x if x != place_holder else random_place_holder for x in example_list ]
split_arg = ' {} '.format(random_place_holder)
example_list = ' '.join(example_list).split(split_arg)
print(example_list)
```

To be honest you might be better off using any of the other solutions if you have an inconvenient place holder such as mentioned by tobias_k.

Decided to time it:
used:

```
example_list = ['This', 'is', None, 'an', None, 'example', 'list', None, '.'] * 10000
place_holder = None
```

I used a longer list so that the creation of the random-string isn't a significant time consuming part, and timing is silly when you aren't using big lists anyway.

This solution:
11.6 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Rakesh' loop solution:
25.8 ms ± 819 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

RoadRunner's groupby:
34.4 ms ± 1.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: Of course, this only works if the placeholder actually is a string, and if that stirng does not appear in any of the other words. I.e. it would not work if the placeholder was, e.g., `None`, `'Q'`, or `''`

Comment: @tobias_k Fair nuff, fixed it for any random placeholder.